# Boarding passes and online check-in

Tags: tickets, check-in

I am having trouble printing out my boarding pass after online check-in. I have two flights (Munich - Istanbul, Istanbul - Washington D.C.), but the system lets me print only one boarding pass for the first flight. Does anybody know why? Will I be given second boarding pass at check-in counter in Munich?

Comment: Unlike at an airport kiosk, when using online check-in I always get only one boarding pass for the flight I'm checking, have you ever had a different experience ?

Comment: No. Actually, I have no experience with flying. Where will I get the second boarding pass then? Thank you so much.

Comment: @blackbird57 It's not uncommon for me to get all the boarding passes for connecting flights (assuming they are all booked as a single ticket) online if the airline is able to provide it. For some itineraries, especially international and codeshare routes, it's not always possible.

Comment: @ZachLipton with electronic boarding passes yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll just throw in my 2c here. I have 40-50 international flights in the last 3 years going from Europe, usually with one more more transfer elsewhere in Europe and typically to the USA (often with transfers there too). Different countries have different requirements for advanced passenger information. Some countries won't let you board without pre-approving your trip. This especially comes into play with trips to the USA where it is possible to travel on the visa waiver program (ESTA) or with a visa. The USA won't let anyone board without confirmation that the person has a visa or ESTA and is not on the no-fly list. Some airlines allow you to provide visa information in advance, and some don't.

What this means is that there may be different restrictions between different parts of your journey that allow you to check-in but not print boarding passes, or not even check-in at all. Sometimes this means that you haven't been approved to take the next flight without someone taking sight of your passport and potentially visa and entering it into the system.

Notwithstanding these type of restrictions, lots of other things can happen to a set of flights that prevent printing boarding passes,e.g.

- requirement to show a credit card to prove it's not a fraudulent payment
- an aircraft change forcing a change of seating meaning that you may have lost your seat and it hasn't been reassigned yet
- overbooking meaning they haven't yet figured out who may be on the flight.
- flight ticketing issues such as flight time changes and the ticket hasn't been re-issued, or segments have become out of order

Since you've been issued the first boarding pass, it's almost certain that if there are any other issues, you can resolve them at the airport and they can probably print your boarding pass for the next segment. Even if you can't, as long as you have enough time you should be able to get it at the transfer desk in Istanbul.

Even if I do the exact same set of flights, I've had occasions where I can't get all boarding passes at once, nor get them at the first airport. It's a bit concerning if you have a short connection, but so far I've never missed a flight yet.

**You'll be ok!**

Answer (score 2):

When you check-in, you do so for the whole flight including any layover. However, depending on the airline and the mode of check-in you may not get all the boarding passes right away.

Printing your boarding pass at the airport (departing or transiting) is also a pretty safe bet, I've done this many times. Just head to your airline counter or a kiosk and check-in from there, you'll get a boarding pass. You're also given a boarding pass at the airline counter when you check your bags too.

Comment: I'd say it depends. I often check in at T-24h for two to four segments and retrieve boarding passes all at once. It depends on the airline.

Comment: I tried to check-in with second ticket number but it's the same. I can see both flights, I've chosen seats.

It says something about "recieved reconfirmation". I filled all the information.

[link](https://i.gyazo.com/f25f34a5f15c196f08ef3982deb3aaad.png) 

[link](https://i.gyazo.com/f71708f3936a3272b9339a8981e00065.png)

Anyway, if I don't manage to print it at home, I can print it at the airport in Turkey, not in Munich, right?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've had plenty of occasions where it hasn't been possible to retrieve boarding pass for subsequent segments. It depends on lots of variables

Comment: @DavidRicherby maybe the check-in, but getting the boarding pass is not always immediate. Still, my answer isn't right, I'll update it.

Comment: The screenshot you linked is hinting that you might not have filled in all the passenger information for your flight to the US (full name, date of birth, passport details). They can't give you a boarding pass without that. Can you check to see whether there's a place to provide that information? Otherwise, it's not a big deal if you can't do it online, just visit the ticket counter in Munich and/or the transfer desk or gate in Istanbul (and be sure to do so at least an hour before departure, per the information in your second screenshot).

Comment: @ZachLipton I've fixed my answer, feel free to add that detail to the answer if you wish

Comment: I've also had occasions where it's even been impossible for the airline to print boarding passes for subsequent segments and I've had to do it at the next transfer. I've had this with out of order ghost segments. I think you need to take out "always" out of any answer!

Comment: Can you have a look at this? 
[link](https://i.gyazo.com/f8c9c1f023fb7fe5d2e3901eda115e99.png)
Is additional document and redress number mendatory? If so, could you explain what is a [redress number](https://i.gyazo.com/fa2dcaf75b5f521b9298210e2adc63e9.png)? I thought it's optional since it let me continue...

Comment: Yes that's the correct form to fill out. Additional document and redress number are not mandatory. A redress number is a number the US Government can give you if people think you're on some kind of security watchlist and you shouldn't be. If you've never heard of a redress number, you don't have one. I assume you already have a valid [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/)?